# How To Send Arguments to a UnitTest Without Global Variables

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

### Problem

Yes I know you shouldn't send arguments to a unittest but in this case I have to so that it can access a piece of hardware within the current framework. For reasons for which the detail is irrelevant, I can't use a simple `board = myBoard.getBoard()` method within the tests, otherwise I wouldn't be here asking you all.

### Horrible Attempt 1

```
class Test(object):

    @staticmethod   
    def __call__(board):

        _board = board
        global _board

        logging.info('Entering a Unit Test')

        suite = unittest.TestLoader()
        suite = suite.loadTestsFromTestCase(TestCase)
        unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

This method will be called upon to perform a unittest at somepoint. This is the way things are set out in the current framework, I'm just following the rules.

You can see here I assign a global variable (horrible). This can then be accessed by the test methods easily:

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def runTest(self):
        logging.critical('running')

    def setUp(self):
        logging.critical('setup')

    def test_Me(self):
        logging.critical('me')
```

The result is it won't enter `runTest` but it will `setUp` before each `test_` method. Pretty much what I'd like, I can deal with it not entering `runTest`

### Horrible Attempt 2

I'd like to do the above but without global variables so I tried this method:

```
class Test(object):
    @staticmethod   
    def __call__(board):

        logging.info('Entering a basic Unit Test')

        suite = unittest.TestSuite() #creates a suite for testing
        suite.addTest(BasicCase(board))
        unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)

class BasicCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, board):

        self.board = board
        logging.critical('init')

        super(BasicCase, self).__init__()    

    def runTest(self):
        logging.critical('runtest')

    def setUp(self):
        logging.critical('reset')
        infra.Reset.__call__(self.board) #allows me to pass the board in a much nicer way

    def test_Connect(self):
        logging.critical('connection')
```

Problem with the above is that it will obviously only do `init`, `setUp` and `runTest` but it'll miss any `test_` methods.

If I add:

```
suite.addTest(BasicCase(board).test_Connect)
```

Then it unnecessarily calls `init` twice and I have to add an extra member variable to `test_Connect` to accept the `test` object. I can deal with this too as I can return a list of the `test_` methods but it just seems like a pain to do. Also I don't think it runs `setUp` every time it enters a new `test_` method. Not ideal.

### So ...

So is there some other method I can use that allows me to quickly run everything like a unittest but allows me to pass the `board` object?

If I should be using a different python module, then please say but I'm using `unittest` due to the lovely outputs and `assert` methods I get.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer here?