# How to skip python unittest with a global parameter

Tags: python, pyqt, python-unittest

I have a set of unit tests in python. Some of them open graphical objects using pyqt, some are just standard standalone tests. My goal is to automatically run at least the tests that don't need to open window, because unless it will wait for user input and then fail.

Note that:

- I can't remove the graphical tests (constraint from the project)
- By default all tests should run, but passing some parameter only non graphical one will run
- My test suite is built using unittest.TestLoader().discover

My best guess would be to pass a global parameter to the TestSuite, so that each test could check the value to know if it should skip or not. But after reading unittest documentation I could not find a way to do this.

I'm aware of this question: [How To Send Arguments to a UnitTest Without Global Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706863/how-to-send-arguments-to-a-unittest-without-global-variables), but I would have expected some unittest configuration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`unittest.skipIf(condition, reason)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.skipIf) and an environment variable to skip the graphical tests.

Create a decorator like:

```
graphical_test = unittest.skipIf(
    os.environ.get('GRAPHICAL_TESTS', False), 'Non graphical tests only'
)
```

Then annotate your graphical tests with `@graphical_test` and run your tests after setting `GRAPHICAL_TESTS=1`

Comment: Ok, I don't really like the use of env vars for such a use, but it seems indeed there's no standard way to do this with unittests. Thanks

Comment: No need for env variable, can theoretically work with any variable like `True` or `False` for accelerating local testing.